# OnActivityResult never called on Redmi 1s for Cordova Camera Plugin

Tags: cordova, camera, onactivityresult

I am developing a Phonegap Application that includes a feature to capture an image from camera and upload that image on some server.

I am using Camera plugin of Cordova (org.apache.cordova.camera). It is working fine on all the devices and devices of Xiaomi too (Mi3i,Mi4). But it is not working on Redmi 1s. Have tried everything that was suggested in community for similar issue, but to no solution. Actually, in any case, the onActivityResult method is not getting called for Xiaomi. This leads app to restart.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems the problem is very strange. can you elaborate little more

Comment: Actually the camera plugin once clicks the image should move to onActivityResult method. onActivityResult in return sends data back to JS call which includes imagePath , but as it never reach onActivityResult, user never reach back to his JS code and hence results in app restart